# How to find first and last occurrences of a particular value in an array?

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to write a program that reads a series of numbers from the user and output when was the first & last times that the number 12 was entered. I can get the program to output when the last time 12 is entered but I'm not sure how to find out when the first 12 occurred. Any help will be appreciated.

This is the code I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int counter = 1, first, last, number, num;

cout << "How many numbers will you enter: ";
cin >> number;

While (counter <= number)(
cout << "Number: ";
cin >> num;

if (num == 12)
{
last = counter;
}
Counter++;
)
return 0;
}
```

Edit & Run

Comment: Initialize `first` to -1, say. In the same place where you update `last`, also update `first` - but only if it's currently -1. This way, you will only update it once, the first time 12 is encountered.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that making people specify how many numbers they're going to enter is not a good interface.  Enter numbers until the input fails, presumably through encountering EOF:  `while (cin >> num) { … }`.

Comment: OT but why do all these assignments ask for the number of numbers first, instead of just going until the user is done entering numbers

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int first = -1, last = -1;

    for (int n, i = 0; std::cin >> n; ++i)
    {
        if (n != 12) { continue; }
        if (first == -1) { first = i; }
        last = i;
    }

    if (first != -1)
    {
        std::cout << "First time: " << first << ", last time: " << last << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No '12' was entered.\n";
    }
}
```

The program ends when the standard input is in EOF state (e.g. when you press Ctrl-D on the terminal, or read from a file).